# How come browser can't store cookies?

Tags: node.js, express, session, cookies, axios

Currently, I am on a solo project, but I've got an issue that is the same as the title.

Client-side is on React with HTTPS.

Server-side is on Express with HTTPS. and they are cross-domain.

when the submit button is clicked, the code below is running.

```
//client side

axios
  .post('https://ohmycounty.me/user/signin', {email : "byron@google.com", password: "example", {
    withCredentials: true,
})


//server side
app.use(session({

  secret: 'example',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {
    sameSite: 'none',
    secure: true
  }
}));

app.use(cors({
  origin: ['https://ohmycounty.xyz'],    // client app's url 
  credentials: true
}));


const { users } = require('../../models');

module.exports = {
  post: (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.session.userid)
    const {
      email,
      password
    } = req.body;

    let session = req.session;

    users.findOne({
      where: {
        email: email,
        password: password
      }
    }).then(result => {
      if (!result) res.status(401).send(JSON.stringify({
        status: false
      }))
      else {
        session.userid = result.id;
        res.status(201).json({
          id: result.id
        })
      }
    })
  }
}
```

I can't find any connect.sid on chrome developer tool applications.

[Chrome Applications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tv1Yi.png)

[Chrome Network Cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6RlR.png)[Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vxial.png)

Waiting for advice from experienced developers.

Any opinion is fine.

Please help me.

Comment: No passwords or other secrets in posts, please. You better change the password in your example code.

Answer (score 1):

The secure attribute should be set if and only if the connection is made over HTTPs. So if you changed it to false, it should work in the dev environment.

```js
  cookie: {
    secure: false
  }
```

From the express-session doc:

cookie.secure
Specifies the boolean value for the Secure Set-Cookie attribute. When truthy, the Secure attribute is set, otherwise, it is not. By default, the Secure attribute is not set.

Note be careful when setting this to true, as compliant clients will not send the cookie back to the server in the future if the browser does not have an HTTPS connection.

Link to the doc: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session